# CSV input to two dimmensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have a read() method and inside I want to separate the Strings(which have spaces between them) and putting them in a two dimensional array, but before that I get rid of all the spaces. After the array initialized, it is given to the CSV constructor and that is creating its own 2D array.
The problem is that I always get the following error: "variable sr might not have been initialized" at CSV csv = new CSV(sr).
How do I make sure that my array gets the valid String?

```
private String[][] tomb;

private CSV(String[][] t2) {
    tomb = new String[t2.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
        tomb[i] = new String[t2[i].length];
        for(int j = 0; j < t2[i].length; j++) {
            tomb[i][j] = t2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public static CSV read(Scanner sc) {

    String[][] sr;    
    int n = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] str = line.split(",");
        sr = new String[str.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            sr[i][n].replaceAll("\\s+","");

        }
        n++;
    }

    CSV csv = new CSV(sr);
    return csv;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the error by setting `sr` to `null` in the initialization:

```
String[][] sr = null;
```

If you want to make sure `sr` was set correctly, you can check if `sr` is still `null` after the while loop completes.

Comment: Thanks! It solved that problem, but of course when I want to run it, NullPointerException comes up at the sr[i][n].replaceAll("\\s+",""); row. I cant give a single String for the array

Comment: @AkosFajszi, you are getting a null pointer exception on that line because `sr` is null. You need to store something in `sr` after `sr = new String[str.length][];`